# Equivalent to Windows User Account Policies (GPO) in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, group-policy

I'm familiar with the group policy functionality in Windows XP Professional that lets you create policies, restrictions, etc. on various parts of Windows for individual user accounts.
I've looked for something similar in Ubuntu, but haven't found anything yet.

I know that Ubuntu lets you create groups which user accounts are members of, which can then govern things such as file permissions, but haven't figured out how to make it do much more than that.

I'm looking for the ability to govern access to things such as internet access, printing, changing user preferences and settings, etc.
Am I missing this functionality built-in somewhere, or is there an application available that I could use for this?
Haven't found one yet, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of [Sabayon](http://live.gnome.org/Sabayon/) and SELinux roles will allow you to specify which users can perform what actions.

Answer (score 0):

System -> Adm -> Users and Groups,

When you select a User, you can go to Advanced Settings and choose access options.

Recall that if a user can use sudo, they can do anything else afterwards.