# Administration suggestions for employees using Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

We're pretty much set on putting Ubuntu LTS (open to alternatives if it's really helpful) on a few new machines for some employees to cut the cost of Windows licenses and seemingly daily glitches.

We run a CentOS 7 server currently, but are looking for suggestions on ways to apply a policy, or otherwise make remote administration of these new Linux boxes easier. If it's going to take more than an hour or two to setup, it's not worth it (there will only be a few machines in production like this for now).

Suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to follow exactly what it is you're asking (as it's too broad), but you may want to check out: [Equivalent to Windows User Account Policies (GPO) in Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/185157/equivalent-to-windows-user-account-policies-gpo-in-ubuntu), and [How to apply group policy and regedit policy in Ubuntu 11.10?](http://serverfault.com/questions/344869/how-to-apply-group-policy-and-regedit-policy-in-ubuntu-11-10)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNOME (on whatever distribution), for desktop settings, similar to applying configuration policy, check out the [GNOME wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators) for instructions. (In short, write your default or possibly mandatory settings to `/etc/dconf/db/site`).

If you're intending to scale up beyond a few machines — or, if you really like to have automation (see Xkcd: [Is it worth the time?](https://xkcd.com/1205/) — and possibly also [The general problem](https://xkcd.com/974/)), I definitely recommend a configuration management system like Ansible*, Chef, or Puppet. Hopefully, you're already using something like this for your servers, so doing it for the desktop won't be much of an additional overhead.

Since you've tagged this "Fedora" — and hey, you're using CentOS for servers, so it's a good match — a more lightweight approach would be to set up a [kickstart file](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pykickstart/blob/master/docs/kickstart-docs.rst) to install systems with preferred installed software and configuration options. This is somewhat less overhead the config management, but of course the disadvantage is that it only covers install time and doesn't keep systems consistent over time.

* disclaimer: I work for Red Hat, and like Fedora, Ansible is a RH-backed project.